# Remove multi lines non-greedy

Tags: text-processing

I have a log file that contains many lines, such as:

```
2015-xx-yy bla bla
2015-11-09 23:59:18.167 Describe ▶ FOO
  dummy
  dummy
  dummy
  dummy
  dummy
  "BAR"
2015-xx-yy foo foo
2015-xx-yy bar bar
2015-xx-yy hello world
   logged bla bla
2015-11-09 23:59:18.169 Describe ▶ FOO
 dummy
 dummy
  dummy
 dummy
  dummy
  "BAR"
```

How to remove the lines from `FOO` to `BAR` so only other lines remains:

```
2015-xx-yy bla bla
2015-xx-yy foo foo
2015-xx-yy bar bar
2015-xx-yy hello world
   logged bla bla
```

What text editor or program that can easily do this?

Comment: so you know, the behavior you describe is *not* greedy because you want your edit to begin at each start and then to stop at the next occurring stop. a greedy match would include all lines beginning with the first occurring start and ending only with the last occurring stop.

Comment: ah i see, i will revise it into `lazy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/FOO/,/BAR/d' <file
```